# How to get csv on s3 with pyspark (No FileSystem for scheme: s3n)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

There are many similar questions on SO, but I simply cannot get this to work.  I'm obviously missing something.

Trying to load a simple test csv file from my s3.

Doing it locally, like below, works.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc

logFile = "sparkexamplefile.csv"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SimpleApp").getOrCreate()

logData = spark.read.text(logFile).cache()

numAs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('a')).count()
numBs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('b')).count()

print("Lines with a: %i, lines with b: %i" % (numAs, numBs))
```

But if I add this below:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "foo")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "bar")
lines = sc.textFile("s3n:///mybucket-sparkexample/sparkexamplefile.csv")
lines.count()
```

I get:

```
No FileSystem for scheme: s3n
```

I've also tried changing `s3` to `spark.sparkContext` without any difference

Also swapping `//` and `///` in the url

Even better, I'd rather do this and go straight to data frame:

```
dataFrame = spark.read.csv("s3n:///mybucket-sparkexample/sparkexamplefile.csv")
```

Also I am slightly AWS ignorant, so I have tried s3, s3n, and s3a to no avail.

I've been around the internet and back but can't seem to resolve the scheme error.  Thanks!

Comment: did you tried lines = sc.textFile("s3://mybucket-sparkexample/sparkexamplefile.csv")?

Comment: @RamdevSharma Yes also tried that, but thanks.  I will update my post.

Answer (score 5):

I think your spark environment didn't get aws jars. You need to add it for using s3 or s3n.

You have to copy required jar files from a hadoop download into the $SPARK_HOME/jars directory. Using the --jars flag or the --packages flag for spark-submit didn't work.

Here my spark version is `Spark 2.3.0` and `Hadoop  2.7.6`
so you have to copy to jars from `(hadoop dir)/share/hadoop/tools/lib/`
to `$SPARK_HOME/jars`.

```
aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
hadoop-aws-2.7.6.jar
```

Comment: I ended up downloading Hadoop and figuring out how to configure and run it.  I also found the files you mentioned.  But can't find the jars folder for Spark.  I installed pyspark using anaconda.  Should I do something else... ?  Thanks!

Comment: check you Spark_home path. Jar folder is available in that path.

Comment: I checked, but I think I must have installed spark wrong because it does not seem a $SPARK_HOME path exists, so I can't find the jar folder.

Comment: How you installed Spark? Is there any environment files for spark? because without that spark won&#39;t work. Might be you add some additional jars for spark???

Answer (score 2):

You must check what is your version of hadoop*. jar files bound to your specific version of pyspark installed on your system, search for folder pyspark/jars and files hadoop*.

The version observed you pass into your pyspark file like this:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.538,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell'
```

This is bit tricky for new joiners on pyspark (I faced this directly my first day with pyspark :-)).

Otherwise I am on Gentoo system with local Spark 2.4.2. Some suggested to install also Hadoop and copy the jars directly to Spark, still should be same version as PySpark is using. So I am creating ebuild for Gentoo for these versions...